# How to deploy vb.net project with SQL Server CE as database

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-ce, setup-deployment

I created a vb.net project and I used SQL Server Compact Edition as my database. Now I want to create an installer for it, for installing on different PCs.

Does it require to install Visual Studio on the client PC? How should I create installer which will include that database file?

Sorry for my bad English.

Please help.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This msdn link shows how to do it:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983326.aspx

There are 2 parts to it:

1. Deploy the database file. This can be done by setting the file to copy local always and updating your connection string to point to this.
2. Deploy the sqlserverce dll's. Follow the instructions in the msdn link which will copy the 7 dll's locally. This means you don't have to install sqlserverce on the individual pcs.

Comment: I followed the step given in that link but it's not working on client machine. It showing the message that visualstudio powerpack is not in global cahe, contact system admin.

Comment: This is what google gives me for it: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?622662-RESOLVED-Deployment-Problem-amp-PowerPacks-10-0-0-0